# Position innerHtml in Angular component

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4

I have following scenario:

**app.component.html**

```
<app-card>
  This is the card body
</app-card>
```

**card.component.html**

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    Header
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">

  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a simple way (like an interpolation) to render the text `This is the card body` into `<div class="card-body">`?

Comment: Did you try placing app-card in that div?

Comment: @Rajat ```app-card``` loads the whole ```card.component.html```, meaning I would enter an endless recursion. And this is also not the porpouse of the component.

Comment: @Rajat https://so-61060715.stackblitz.io (already with the solution from @Dimitar)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ng-content`:

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    Header
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

in app.component.html file 
try below code

```
<ng-content>
{{ write your property here }}
</ng-content>
```